# retina display graphics on the iPad not showing up - why?

Tags: iphone, ipad, retina-display

I've installed my iPhone app on an iPad. When I tap this "2x" button, the app gets scaled up, but it doesn't use my retina display graphics. Isn't that somewhat stupid? I am sure I did something wrong!

What must I set in the info.plist or elsewhere that the iPad will use my retina display graphics when the app is watched in 2x mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it literally just scales up the screen. It may be a bit lame but that's by design. Note that even the text is pixel-doubled.

If you want to make better use of the screen you have to make a "Universal" app.

Comment: True, but interestingly, MapKit shows maps in high resolution when scaled.

Comment: I remember that some Apple guy talked about the ipad would automatically use retina display graphics. Incredible they don't do it. Really.

Comment: @openfrog If they were going to do it, it would be in iOS 4.2. I've not looked at the docs, and even if I had I couldn't say as it's still covered by the NDA!

Comment: The Skype app sizes the profile pictures and they look nice. :O

Answer (score 0):

If you use a hi-res image (not called @2x) in your app, then size the UIImageView half the size of the image it will appear crisp on the iPhone, retina, and iPad scaled up.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your retina image naming convention is correct.
For retina image naming convention should be @2x.Suppose if your regular image name is like 
icon.png then for retina it should be icon@2x.png.